# Man in the middle - proxy - too slow

Tags: python, soap, proxy

I've developed a simple transparent proxy script in Python that changes a string in the server-client traffic.
[Source Here](http://yabahaus.blogspot.pt/2011/02/outlook-2010-talking-to-exchange-2000.html)
It was used with SMTP and now I have changed it to other application.
My problem is that after it changes the 1st defined string, I need it to stop processing the messages, only pass them to the correct host.
Or...If there's any other software that does this, it would be great.
Not that I don't trust my own code, but something well tested, and with better performance would be great.
Also, keep in mind, the original code would handle little traffic, just a few e-mails, this new one, will handle a lot, several SOAP messages passing around between the hosts, and with multiple clients.
It's working, but, every now and then I get a "server disconnected" message in the client app.
(Sorry my lousy english, will update the post if needed, to better understanding)

Comment: Python threading is not particularly scalable, so you might want to use a framework like Twisted.

Comment: Well, initially this was just a little hack :) I was wondering if someone knows some kind of software to acomplish this ? (string replacement)